# How does this jenkins groovy script work?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

This is my groovy Script on Jenkins

```
def gitURL = "http://bitbucket.webapp.intern.de/scm/myproject.git"
def command = "git ls-remote -h $gitURL"

def proc = command.execute()  // line 3
proc.waitFor()              

if ( proc.exitValue() != 0 ) {
   println "Error, ${proc.err.text}"
   System.exit(-1)
}

def branches = proc.in.text.readLines().collect {    // line 9
    it.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//, '')    // line 10
}

return branches
```

First I do not understand anything. How on line 3 can you call execute on command which is supposed to be a string ??

What type is variable branches in line 9 ???
Is branches a String ??

What is it.replaceAll in line 10 ??? I know replaceAll as method from String. But it has 2 parameters.
I do not see 2 parameters here.

Now I somehow understand branches contains all branches. What I want to do. I only want to have
branches which contain "-REST" it their names. How can I do this ??

My intention was using java. But it does not work.

```
List<String> branchesNew = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String branch : branchesNew)
{
     if(branch.contains("-REST"))
            branchesNew.add(branch);
}
```

Comment: Don't worry, if your first approach with Groovy is a little frustrating. I think that this is a common feeling. :) IMHO you can do following: read the official documentation at groovy-lang.org, install groovy locally and test your single commands with groovish (similar to jshell in java), test your code with your own playground Jenkins project (not every groovy script is working in Jenkins out of the box, because of several reasons).

Answer (score 1):

**line 3**: this is a Groovy feature, see http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management

**line 9**: it's a collection (a list, for instance) given as output of the `collect` method. see also http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_collections

**line 10**: the second argument is ''. it replaces the regexp matches (branch prefixes) with an empty string.

You can filter all your wanted branches using the `findAll` method on collections. Following the given example:

```
def branchesNew = proc.in.text.readLines().findAll{ it.contains('-REST') }
```

Look at [Filtering and searching](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#List-Filtering) for all related manipulation methods.